# styled-components creating css class inline in react or preact

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components, preact

I used styled-components in a solidjs project before. There is a function named "css" in it that can create a class dynamically and assign it to a tag, the code is something like this

```
import { css } from "solid-styled-components";
```

and

```
<div class={ css`
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
`}>
   blah blah
</div>
```

can I use something like that in preact? I don't want to make a new component for that small div

Comment: can't you just do an inline style? If this is not something that would be ever reused it would make sense to just add the inline and forget about it

Answer (score 1):

I think the `css` prop is as close as you can get, docs for which can be [found here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop).

```
<div
  css={`
    background: papayawhip;
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text};
  `}
/>
<Button
  css="padding: 0.5em 1em;"
/>
```

You will need to use the [Babel plugin](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin) for this though.

---

> I used styled-components in a solidjs project before.

It's worth noting that `solid-styled-components` isn't actually `styled-components` -- it's a vaguely similar thing from the creator of Solid (rather than the `styled-components` team) and deviates from the API quite a bit. It's Solid's take on the Styled Components idea, not Solid bindings for Styled Components, if that makes sense.

You might have more luck with what you're after in another library besides `styled-components` itself.

Comment: yeah, I've done a brief check on the Emotion document. it seems it could do this better. I should do more investigation on it.